# Derivative of $\int\limits_x^5 \cos^2(t^4)dt$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I wish to find the derivative of $$\int_x^5\cos^2(t^4)dt.$$

I've tried many ways and cannot figure out how to integrate the inside of $t^4$. I know that I probably have to use integration by parts but I don't know how, thank you.

Comment: I'm only guessing, but is it possible that the problem you're working on defines $F(x)$ to be the expression above, and then asks you to compute $F'(a)$ for some value of $a$? If so, computing an antiderivative is not actually necessary ... which is the "aha" you're supposed to have.

Comment: Yes you are right so how would I go about solving F'a without computing the integral?

Comment: You could use the fundamental theorem of calculus (specifically people refer to it as the second part of the fundamental theorem of calculus)

Comment: @ineedmathhelp so please add this to your question.

Comment: You would carefully read the chapter that describes the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus...

Comment: Reverse the in limits of integration: $-\int_4^x cos^2(t^4)dt$.  Now  use the "Fundamental Theorem of Calculus":  The derivative of $\int_a^x f(t)dt$ is f(x).

Comment: By the way this is an example of the xy problem. meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Have a look at Leibnitz's rule for differentiation of integrals. Perhaps more useful to know about such a general method rather than having to rely on tricks and experience, especially if the question were slightly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering in light of the comments to the question.$$F(x)= \int_x^5cos^2(t^4)dt = I(5) - I(x)  $$
Denoting the anti-derivative by $I$.
Now, differentiate both sides with respect to $x$. We get $$F^{'}(x) = -\cos^2(x^4) $$.

Comment: ok I got that answer too, thank you everyone for the help!